# systemctl disable name.service doesn't persist after reboot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, systemd

I'm trying to find a way to disable Bluetooth on Ubuntu 16.04 at startup , the one way i kept stumbling upon online is using systemd

Basically

First, stop the service:

sudo systemctl stop bluetooth.service

Then disable it:

sudo systemctl disable bluetooth.service

Check:

sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service

https://askubuntu.com/questions/744640/best-way-to-deactivate-bluetooth-on-system-startup-with-systemd-and-not-upstar

but every time i reboot it's back on and i couldn't find anyone online complaining that systemd disable command didn't work like in my case

even on the ubuntu wiki it says that it should work what am i doing wrong ?

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers

here is the output when i run these commands

```
    mohamed@mohamed-UX330UAK:~$ sudo systemctl stop bluetooth.service
[sudo] password for mohamed: 
mohamed@mohamed-UX330UAK:~$ sudo systemctl disable bluetooth.service
Synchronizing state of bluetooth.service with SysV init with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install...
Executing /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install disable bluetooth
insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (empty) of script `bluetooth' overrides LSB defaults (2 3 4 5).
insserv: warning: current stop runlevel(s) (0 1 2 3 4 5 6) of script `bluetooth' overrides LSB defaults (0 1 6).
insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (empty) of script `bluetooth' overrides LSB defaults (2 3 4 5).
insserv: warning: current stop runlevel(s) (0 1 2 3 4 5 6) of script `bluetooth' overrides LSB defaults (0 1 6).
mohamed@mohamed-UX330UAK:~$ sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; disabled; vendor prese
   Active: inactive (dead) since Wed 2017-04-26 19:56:04 AEST; 23s ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 882 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Status: "Quitting"

Apr 26 19:42:19 mohamed-UX330UAK bluetoothd[882]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1
Apr 26 19:42:19 mohamed-UX330UAK bluetoothd[882]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1
Apr 26 19:42:19 mohamed-UX330UAK bluetoothd[882]: RFCOMM server failed for Heads
Apr 26 19:42:34 mohamed-UX330UAK bluetoothd[882]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=
Apr 26 19:42:34 mohamed-UX330UAK bluetoothd[882]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=
Apr 26 19:56:04 mohamed-UX330UAK systemd[1]: Stopping Bluetooth service...
Apr 26 19:56:04 mohamed-UX330UAK bluetoothd[882]: Terminating
Apr 26 19:56:04 mohamed-UX330UAK bluetoothd[882]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=
Apr 26 19:56:04 mohamed-UX330UAK bluetoothd[882]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=
Apr 26 19:56:04 mohamed-UX330UAK systemd[1]: Stopped Bluetooth service.
lines 1-17/17 (END)...skipping...
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; disabled; vendor prese
   Active: inactive (dead) since Wed 2017-04-26 19:56:04 AEST; 23s ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 882 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Status: "Quitting"

Apr 26 19:42:19 mohamed-UX330UAK bluetoothd[882]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1
Apr 26 19:42:19 mohamed-UX330UAK bluetoothd[882]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1
Apr 26 19:42:19 mohamed-UX330UAK bluetoothd[882]: RFCOMM server failed for Heads
Apr 26 19:42:34 mohamed-UX330UAK bluetoothd[882]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=
Apr 26 19:42:34 mohamed-UX330UAK bluetoothd[882]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=
Apr 26 19:56:04 mohamed-UX330UAK systemd[1]: Stopping Bluetooth service...
Apr 26 19:56:04 mohamed-UX330UAK bluetoothd[882]: Terminating
Apr 26 19:56:04 mohamed-UX330UAK bluetoothd[882]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=
Apr 26 19:56:04 mohamed-UX330UAK bluetoothd[882]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=
Apr 26 19:56:04 mohamed-UX330UAK systemd[1]: Stopped Bluetooth service.
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
lines 1-17/17 (END)...skipping...
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Wed 2017-04-26 19:56:04 AEST; 23s ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 882 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Status: "Quitting"

Apr 26 19:42:19 mohamed-UX330UAK bluetoothd[882]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.79 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Apr 26 19:42:19 mohamed-UX330UAK bluetoothd[882]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.79 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Apr 26 19:42:19 mohamed-UX330UAK bluetoothd[882]: RFCOMM server failed for Headset Voice gateway: rfcomm_bind: Address already in use (98)
Apr 26 19:42:34 mohamed-UX330UAK bluetoothd[882]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.43 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Apr 26 19:42:34 mohamed-UX330UAK bluetoothd[882]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.43 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Apr 26 19:56:04 mohamed-UX330UAK systemd[1]: Stopping Bluetooth service...
Apr 26 19:56:04 mohamed-UX330UAK bluetoothd[882]: Terminating
Apr 26 19:56:04 mohamed-UX330UAK bluetoothd[882]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.79 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Apr 26 19:56:04 mohamed-UX330UAK bluetoothd[882]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.79 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Apr 26 19:56:04 mohamed-UX330UAK systemd[1]: Stopped Bluetooth service.
```

Comment: I got the same issue with updatedb and mariadb, this is the only mention of similar issue that I've found so far. Not solved yet.

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps the service is being started by a dependency. There is a [third level of "off" with systemd](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/three-levels-of-off) that you can try, called "masking":

```
systemctl mask bluetooth.service
```

Once masked, a service can't be started at all, even manually. You can 'unmask' it later.

Answer (score -2):

Here is how you can create a script that will run on startup and perform an action to kill the Bluetooth service, and that would be the following (I use nano, feel free to use any other text editor):

**Step 1:** Navigate to the folder

```
cd /etc/systemd/system/
```

**Step 2:** First create a script that will kill the Bluetooth service once run:

```
nano bluetoothkill.sh
```

**Step 3:** Enter the following code, save and exit:

```
#!/bin/bash
rfkill block bluetooth
exit 0
```

**Step 4:** Create a foo.service file in the same folder /etc/systemd/system/ :

```
nano foo.service
```

**Step 5:** Enter the following code, save and exit:

```
[Unit]
Details=Additional startup scripts
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/etc/systemd/system/bluetoothkill.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

**Step 6:** Run the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo chmod 744 bluetoothkill.sh
```

**Step 7:** Run the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo systemctl start foo.service
```

**Step 8:** Restart the machine and on the next boot you will notice that the Bluetooth service is no longer enabled by default on startup. You can still enable it when ever you like in the settings, or the terminal it is behaving without any errors.

*If you like to add more scripts on startup, you can always edit the foo.service file and add additional lines under the [Service] bracket to run additional scripts on startup, for example:*

```
ExecStart=/full-script-filepath/newscript.sh
```